# Control polling behavior of javascript adapter deployed in a cluster

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Scenario:

HTTP adapter that is meant for push functionality based on Event source. It uses
polling mechanism.

Issue:

Adapter is deployed in 2 nodes, horizontally clustered with 2 JVM each, so in
total it is deployed in 4 JVM. When the polling starts, the adapter runs in only one JVM i.e it does not poll from all the 4 JVM.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi JVM scenario where a polling adapter is deployed, the specific JVM where the polling should start cannot be controlled and it can run in any one of the 4 JVM. This is the default behavior at least in the context of product version here (7.1).

Also it is not possible to have the adapter start polling in all the 4 JVM.

In such scenarios, it is advised to have a common location that all the 4 JVM need to point to, in order to look for any events to be picked up, as a means to trigger the push notification. This will avoid the issues down the line when the JVM's need to be restarted and so the polling can start in any of the 4 JVM